# Display current time- hour and minute with best practices angular 7

Tags: html, angular7

I want to display the current time on the display (hours and minutes).

How can I do it most efficiently in terms of performance

Using Angular 7

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can import formatDate from the angular common/package and then you can pass the data Here is the example :-

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {formatDate } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  name = 'Angular 7';
  today= new Date();
  todaysDataTime = '';
  constructor() {
    this.todaysDataTime = formatDate(this.today, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a', 'en-US', '+0530');
  }
}
```

Working example output link is given below :-
[StackBlitz](https://angular-h63y8e.stackblitz.io)

Or the best way is you can use datePipe module which formats date according to local rules.

Here is the link for reference :- [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)